# What is the preferred way to pass the reactor to a protocol in Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted, reactor

In the [twisted docs](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/api/twisted.internet.reactor.html), it says:

> New application code should prefer to pass and accept the reactor as a parameter where it is needed, rather than relying on being able to import this module to get a reference. This simplifies unit testing and may make it easier to one day support multiple reactors (as a performance enhancement), though this is not currently possible.

What is the preferred way of doing this? In particular, what is the best way to pass it to a protocol? (Especially when the standard twisted.internet.protocol.Factory is all that's needed.)

*Edit*: To clarify, since the protocol is not instantiated directly, I am wondering if the method below is the preferred way, or if there is a better way of allowing access to the reactor in the protocol.

```
class MyFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def __init__(self, rct):
        self.reactor = rct

class MyProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reactor = None

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.reactor = self.factory.reactor

if __name__=="__main__":
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    f = MyFactory(reactor)
    f.protocol = MyProtocol
    reactor.listenXXX(whatever)
    reactor.run()
```

It seems a little bit silly to make a factory class solely for the purpose of accessing the reactor, since wanting access to the reactor must be fairly common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems a little bit silly to make a factory class solely for the purpose of accessing the reactor

A lot of programming tasks are "a little bit silly".  The state of the art in programming is actually a lot silly in most areas, in my experience.

But if you're using a sufficiently new version of Twisted, then you can do what you want like this:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory

factory = Factory.forProtocol(YourProtocol, reactor)
```

If you're using an older version of Twisted without this API then you can do this instead:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientCreator

ClientCreator(reactor, YourProtocol, reactor).connectTCP(...)
```

But this is only for clients which isn't specifically what your question is about.

The idea of [making the `reactor` attribute that most transports already have part of the guaranteed transport interface](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/3205) (which it is not currently part of) has been discussed by the Twisted development team from time to time.  If you want a better answer to this question then you could try motivating some action on that front.

Comment: Thanks. By silly I just meant that I felt like I was probably doing it in a poor way. But it seems like without the `forProtocol` API, making a factory class is the way to go, in general.